# Swift Rope Verlets

Tags: swift, verlet-integration

I'm trying to implement a verlet rope in swift. I'm running into the problem where when trying to fix the position of the point masses from constraints, they very rapidly grow apart and then the coordinates become NaNs. Any idea what could be wrong in my code?

```
import Foundation

private let DEF_POINT_COUNT = 10
private let CONST_ITERATIONS = 5

@objc class PointMass: DebugPrintable {
    var point: NSPoint
    private var oldPoint: NSPoint

    var x: Double {
        get { return Double(point.x) }
    }

    var y: Double {
        get { return Double(point.y) }
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        get { return "\(point)" }
    }

    init(_ point: NSPoint) {
        self.point = point
        self.oldPoint = point
    }

    func updatePosition() {
        let dx = point.x - oldPoint.x
        let dy = (point.y - oldPoint.y)

        oldPoint = point

        point = NSPoint(x: point.x + dx, y: point.y + dy)
    }

    func updatePosition(point: NSPoint) {
        let dx = point.x - self.point.x
        let dy = point.y - self.point.y
        self.oldPoint = NSPoint(x: oldPoint.x + dx, y: oldPoint.y + dy)
        self.point = point
    }
}

struct Constraint {
    var p1: PointMass
    var p2: PointMass
    var len: Double

    func fixPoints() {
        let dx = p2.x - p1.x
        let dy = p2.y - p1.y

        let dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

        let diff = (dist - len)/len

        p2.updatePosition(NSPoint(x: p2.x - diff*dx*0.5, y: p2.y - diff*dy*0.5))
        p1.updatePosition(NSPoint(x: p1.x + diff*dx*0.5, y: p1.y + diff*dy*0.5))
    }
}

@objc class Rope: NSObject {
    let points: [PointMass]
    let constraints: [Constraint]

    init(anchor: NSPoint, end: NSPoint, length: Double, count: Int = DEF_POINT_COUNT) {
        let anchorPoint = PointMass(anchor)
        let endPoint = PointMass(end)

        let dx = (anchorPoint.x - endPoint.x)/Double(count)
        let dy = (anchorPoint.y - endPoint.y)/Double(count)

        let constraintLength = length/Double(count)

        var points = [endPoint]
        var constraints: [Constraint] = []

        for i in 1...count {
            let prevPoint = points[i-1]
            let newPoint = PointMass(NSPoint(x: prevPoint.x + dx, y: prevPoint.y + dy))

            let constraint = Constraint(p1: prevPoint, p2: newPoint, len: constraintLength)

            points.append(newPoint)
            constraints.append(constraint)
        }

        self.points = points
        self.constraints = constraints
    }

    func update(anchor: NSPoint, endPoint: NSPoint) {
        points.first?.updatePosition(endPoint)
        points.last?.updatePosition(anchor)

        for point in points {
            point.updatePosition()
        }

        for i in 0...CONST_ITERATIONS {
            for constraint in constraints {
                constraint.fixPoints()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The problem was in the `fixPoints()` method, as I suspected.

The line

```
let diff = (dist - len)/len
```

should be instead

```
let diff = (len - dist)/dist
```